# amazon S3 bucket access with Rstudio

Tags: r, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have successfully accessed and queried amazon redshift with R (rstudio) using RPostgreSQL where I have

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host="****.redshift.amazonaws.com", port=5439,dbname="***", user="***", password="****")
```

I can then run my query with:

```
dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT DISTINCT(vin) FROM rawdata")
```

While my queries dont take too long to run, saving my files to my personal computer do. I think it would be faster to save the .csv files that I generate to an Amazon S3 bucket. I have already set one up. I just dont know how to do it from R studio.

I have been able to access my S3 bucket with SQL Workbench with the code:

```
UNLOAD
('SELECT * FROM rawdata
ORDER BY timestamp')
TO 's3://data-**-**/file_name'
credentials '***'
delimiter ','
PARALLEL OFF
GZIP;
```

but I would like to do a similar function in Rstudio (Version 0.98.109). Does anyone have example code for this perhaps with a sample SQL query? I could run it in SQL workbench but I have the SQl queries embedded in other code that I prefer to run in Rstudio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some packages out there which might help you in that, not in CRAN but still worth the try:

Ex: https://github.com/armstrtw/AWS.tools